# include the related entities values in the result of a doctrine query

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm doing a Doctrine query, and the results include the properties of the queried entity, but not it doesn't "follow" and fetch the values of the related entities.

E.g. I have this query inside of the `OfertaRepository`:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('o');
$query->select('o');
$query->leftJoin(Pais::class, 'p', 'with', 'o.idPais = p.id');
$query->leftJoin( Contrato::class, 'c', 'with', 'o.idTipoContrato = c.id');
$query->andWhere('p.nombreCorto = :pais');
$query->andWhere('o.activa = 1');
$query->andWhere('o.eliminado is NULL');
$query->andWhere('o.caducidad > :hoy');
$query->setParameter('pais', $pais)->setParameter('hoy', new \DateTime());

return $query->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

The entity `Oferta` has:

```
/**
 * @var \Application\Entity\Pais
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Pais")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_pais", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * })
 */
private $idPais;


/**
 * @var \Application\Entity\TipoContrato
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\TipoContrato")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_tipo_contrato", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * })
 */
private $idTipoContrato;
```

All referenced tables ( `tipo_contrato`, `pais`, etc) exist and the relationships work for filtering data on queries, for example.

But my results from the `$query->getQuery()->getArrayResult()` expression do not include data from these relations.

It wont even include the ids from this fields. E.g., for any one record it will only include these fields:

- id
- alt
- nombre"
- nombreAlt
- descripcion
- poblacion
- vacantes
- horarioIni
- horarioFin
- url
- tag
- creado
- caducidad
- modificado
- eliminado
- activa

Which are all valid fields, but do not include any fields that are a many-to-one relationship.

How can I include these values for this query, and for this query only? E.g. without changing the entities definition so **all** queries are affected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at: `$query->select('o');` I'd say (think of it in terms of SQL) that is all you are selecting. Get some commas in there. I'd try something like this:

```
$query->select('o', 'p', 'c');
```

What I was trying to do first time should have been an array. Not a comma delimited string like I showed. See source:

```
$selects = is_array($select) ? $select : func_get_args();
```

So either an array or a list of arguments should work.

**Update:**

Maybe you are just missing the `from`? Totally missed that.  Here I'll share some code that I know works. Maybe you will see something. Pretty sure you just need a `from` clause and the multiple obj references on the `select` part.

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('aimg', 'ai');
        $qb->from('OAS\Entity\AuctionImage', 'aimg');
        $qb->leftJoin('aimg.auctionItem', 'ai', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'ai.lotNumber = aimg.lotNumber AND ai.auction = aimg.auction');
        $qb->where('aimg.auction = :auction')->setParameter('auction', $this->_auction);
        $qb->andWhere('aimg.isDeleted = :boolFalse')->setParameter('boolFalse', 0);
        $qb->andWhere('aimg.auctionItem IS NULL');
        $qb->orderBy('aimg.lotNumber', 'asc');
        $results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Man, I'm glad this didn't work. I would have felt terribly silly. I'm sure that by the end of this, that will still happen though. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Nope, same result, exactly.

Comment: Same result. The SQL produced seems better, though. Although the results aren't included in the result array. But the SQL includes stuff as `p1_.id AS id_16, p1_.nombre AS nombre_17,` (etc), where `p1_.id` reference `LEFT JOIN pais p1_`...

Comment: The SQL produced was identical, as far as I can see, as including the commas inside the original string. E.g. `'o, p, c'` == `'o', 'p', 'c'`. As far as I could see, at least.

Comment: LOL where is the `->from`?

Comment: Wait, something else is happening. The related data **is** coming through, but as additional rows... E.g. Row 0 has the values for `o`, row 1 the values for `p`, row 2 the values for `c`...

Comment: Your first solution kinda works (without the "from" clause, its added by Doctrine directly). Apparently `getArrayResult` is messing up the results. It seems I have an additional problem.

Comment: Hmm. I see I use `getResult` and you use `getArrayResult` Probably look at `getResult(2)` /  `\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY`? Not sure what might be going on there.

Comment: getArrayResult and getResult(2) are exactly the same thing. It turns I don't even need to add the additional tables in my select. The whole thing is about getResult part. So I'm actually getting the values, I was just missing them because of getArrayResults. A normal getResults gets the values alright, although as an array of objects I can't easily transform into a JsonModel. I feel awful about this question, though.